# How to override default theme button mat-badge-content in angular material 15?

Tags: css, angular-material, themes

My default theme is Indigo pink. I want to change the color of badge content from blue to light grey. Please help!

[image]

Here is my .html code

```
  <button mat-raised-button style="color: #4A993A; background-color: white !important;" (click)="showUpClients()" matBadge="Up" [ngClass]="disableUp" matBadgePosition="before" >
           38 
       </button> &nbsp;
            <button mat-raised-button style="color: #D13212; background-color: white !important" (click)="showDownClients()" matBadge="Down" [ngClass]="disableDown" matBadgePosition="before">
          527
       </button>
```

Here is my .css code to override it.

```
.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-overlap.mat-badge-before .mat-badge-content{
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    min-width: 32px;
    min-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    top: -20px;
    right: -22px;
    background: #424242 !important;
}
.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-before .mat-badge-content {
  background: #424242 !important;
}

.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-above .mat-badge-content{
  background: #424242 !important;

}
```